# How to modify the code of the dependencies of a maven Project

Tags: java, maven, imagej

I just started to do some work on the ImageJ project. This software is developped in Java using Maven as a build system and is split intp numerous sub-projects/modules. I would like to work and modify some of these sub/projects and have them compile in one go by the main Maven project.

How can I (if possible) configure maven to use the local source code instead of the distant Jar file to build the ImageJ Software ?

I can see that each dependency is listed in the pom.xml file of the main project but I did not find a solution to use the local source code instead.

Comment: use dependencies on snapshots, and build your snapshot locally

Comment: Hi, thank you but could you give some details ?

Comment: ... those are the details. what more do you want me to say?

Answer (score 1):

If you build ImageJ with a certain version number (like `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT`) by using `mvn clean install`, you can use this version of ImageJ in the dependencies of your other project.

You cannot reference source code directly by Maven (although there is a feature "Workspace Resolution" in Eclipse that does that).

Comment: Hi, I am looking into Eclipse Workspace resolution, which may be what I am looking for. Thanks for your insight

Comment: @M.Desharnais you mean it's code that isn't yours you want to alter?

Comment: Yes that's it.
I know that imagej uses a plugin system but I also want to dive deep in its core code.

Comment: @JFMeier if I perform `mvn clean install` on project X, and In project Y I have a dependency of project X. Then would it pick X.jar from the local repo instead of remote?

Comment: @GovindaSakhare Yes, if the version numbers match.